# nginx odoo port and https redirection

Tags: nginx, https, odoo

Accessing example.com:8069 dosent redirect to https://example.com, accessing myip:8069 dosent redirect to https://example.com. The only thing that redirect correctly is when  you enter just myip.
i have tried adding this, but then nginx fails to start:

```
 server {
     listen [::]:8069;
     listen 8069;

     server_name myip:8069;

     return 301 https://odoo.example.com$request_uri;
 }
```

this is my entire nginx config:

```
    upstream odooserver {
     server 127.0.0.1:8069;
 }

 server {
     listen [::]:80;
     listen 80;

     server_name odoo.example.com www.odoo.example.com myip;

     return 301 https://odoo.example.com$request_uri;
 }

 server {
     listen [::]:443 ssl;
     listen 443 ssl;

     server_name www.odoo.example.com;

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.example.com/privkey.pem;

     return 301 https://odoo.example.com$request_uri;
 }

 server {
     listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
     listen 443 ssl http2;

     server_name odoo.example.com;

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.example.com/privkey.pem;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_error.log;

     proxy_read_timeout 720s;
     proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
     proxy_send_timeout 720s;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

     location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://odooserver;
     }

     location ~* /web/static/ {
         proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
         proxy_buffering on;
         expires 864000;
         proxy_pass http://odooserver;
     }

     gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
     gzip on;
 }
```

How do i myip:8069 and odoo.example.com:8069 to redirect to https://odoo.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Just define the server_name like in the nginx documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}
```

In your config ('server_name myip:8069;'), your have to define the domain (space separated as in example, for multiple domains or wildcard definition)

Comment: i could just add server_name _: to cover all hosts, but that still dosent fix it. @aNj